# Compiz not staying in Kubuntu 11.10

Tags: compiz, kubuntu

I installed Kubuntu 11.10 on my computer that already runs Unity. I want to use Compiz so I can get the magic lamp effect and I already have KDE Compatibility checked in it but when I go into terminal and type "compiz --replace" it will give me the effect I want but it will also change the window decoration to Unity's Ambiance and I can't seem to change it. When I log out and log back in, Comppiz is gone and I'm back to how I was before. Any ideas as to what's going on and possible resolutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiz is a window manager.  KDE has its own, KWin.  If you switch to Compiz, KWin is replaced by Compiz, and Compiz has its own window decorations.

Logging out and in doesn't keep Compiz because you haven't set Compiz to run at startup--you just started it manually.

I'm not sure what you're wanting here.  Your question isn't very clear.  KWin has its own magic lamp-like effect built-in.  Have you tried it?